# Is zeroing out values on the stack and arguments overkill?

Tags: memory, hardening, c

I generally zero out memory the moment it's served its usefulness, but only with heap-allocated chunks.  Is it a sin (or overkill) to do the same with arguments and stack values?  Thanks in advance.

Edit:

Here's an example of what I mean:

```
void foo(int arg0, int *arg1) {
    int local;

    /* ... */

    arg0 = 0; /* passed by value, so zero the copied value */
    arg1 = 0; /* 0 instead of NULL (NULL might not be 0) */
    local = 0; /* MIGHT be on the stack, depending on optimizations */

    /* Edit: now those values should be safe for FUTURE use */
}
```

Comment: I think it's going to be highly OS and possibly HW dependent.  At the very least dependent on what you're storing in memory.  FWIW most modern OSes clear out the memory when allocated to a new process.

Comment: @SteveSether I'm wary of trusting the kernel's allocator, so I'm hoping to keep data lifespan as short as possible.

Comment: I don't know that you should be dis-trustful of the allocator.  It's a relatively unlikely thing to go wrong.  You should possibly be more distrustful of the memory still accessible while the process is still live.  Heartbleed, for instance.  Or possibly things like the various spectre and similar side channel attacks.  Zeroing out memory isn't costless of course.

Comment: function parameters and local variables 'disappear' when the function exits.  So there is no need to set them to zero before exiting the function.  However, is it a good idea to initialize all local variables BEFORE using them

Comment: Do note that with the default optimizer settings, most C compilers will simply ignore your code that zeroes out memory that "shouldn't" affect anything and not actually zero out that memory.

Comment: @user3629249 if function leaves some secret on the stack when it exits, then that secret may still be readable by a buffer overflow in another function that's executed afterwards.

Comment: @Peteris I primarily use `gcc` without the `-O` flag.  Are any optimizations made regardless of whether the `-O` flag is supplied?

Comment: @user3629249 I'm particularly worried about the concern raised by Peteris

Comment: @hiten I wouldn't want to write code that is only secure with certain compiler flags. There are ways to securely erase stack variables.

Comment: @Peteris Carnegie Mellon has some good resources on this https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/MEM03-C.+Clear+sensitive+information+stored+in+reusable+resources https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/MSC06-C.+Beware+of+compiler+optimizations

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The C standard specifies the behavior of code in terms of an abstract machine.  This specification does not know about concepts such as "the stack".  It knows variables with "automatic storage duration", meaning variables which are "gone" when the scope they've been defined in is left.

From the perspective of the C standard the code `local = 0;` has only the effect that subsequent accesses to `local` will yield the value `0`.

Now, even though it's not explicitly called like this in the standard, [C has an "as-if rule"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46455917/1116364).  This means that a compiler is free to implement the code however it likes as long as the "observable behavior" remains the same as that of the code when "run" by the abstract machine.

`local = 0;` has *no* observable behavior (assuming there's no code using `local` in an observable way after the assignment).  Therefore, the compiler is allowed to discard that assignment; regardless of optimization settings.

**Thus, "zero-ing" like this is a sin because it is not guaranteed to actually do anything and adds clutter to the code, making it less readable.**  Note that this also applies to dynamically allocated memory!

**edit** *It's questionable if it's even possible to make sure the compiler doesn't optimize the zeroing away, see [this blog post, linked post and comments](https://www.daemonology.net/blog/2014-09-04-how-to-zero-a-buffer.html)*
**/edit**

To really zero a variable You need to make this assignment "observable".  The C standard luckily includes means to do so: via an assignment to an object of `volatile` qualified type.

So with a function like ...

```
void zero_out(unsigned char volatile * memory, size_t size)
{
  while(size--)
  {
    *memory++ = 0;
  }
}
```

... You can be sure that after calling `zero_out(&local, sizeof(local))` the memory region (if any) where `local` is/was kept is zero.  *This disables any smart optimizations by the compiler, though, so for larger memory regions it might be slow!*

Even better than my above function is to use a function provided by either the standard or the compiler to achieve the same (because it might be optimized):

- C11 has `memset_s` which won't be optimized away.  Problematic because `memset_s` is only optional, and currently not available on e.g. GCC and Clang.
- MSVC has `SecureZeroMemory`

There are also other (potentially better) ways to implement my `zero_out` from above:

- A `volatile` function pointer:

  ```
   void * (*volatile memset_here_to_stay)(void *, int, size_t) = memset;
   void zero_out(void * p, size s)
   {
     memset_here_to_stay(p, 0, s);
   }
  ```
- An "external" function, implemented in assembly (or generated by another translation unit).  Attention! Link time optimization might make this ineffective ...

Comment: Based on https://www.daemonology.net/blog/2014-09-04-how-to-zero-a-buffer.html, it sounds like neither the function you show above nor your related ideas are guaranteed to actually zero the buffer.  Essentially, the volatile keyword does not help for our purposes.  Only explicit-zeroing library functions such as memset_s, explicit_bzero, and the like can guarantee zero'ing, because the library explicitly disables Dead Store Elimination for their definitions.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, adding it to the answer.